# How to validate response headers by Content-Length and Content-Type before downloading an image via Picasso?

Tags: java, android, http, picasso, okhttp

I am in a situation where I want to verify the HTTP response headers before actually deciding to download or not an image via Picasso into an ImageView. The specific reason is that there is no other way for me to tell if the image in the right format and right size without downloading it, just to realize I have to throw it out as it does not fit the criteria set.

The flow is something along the lines:

```
// 1. Ask a specific Profiles Service for a given user-id
// 2. Process the response and get the avatar URI from it
// 3. Call the avatar URI to validate the headers
if (validate(response.headers)) {
    // 4. Download avatar image using Picasso into given ImageView
} else {
    // 5. Don't download anything but show a placeholder image.
}
```

First off, I know that Picasso has built in functionalities to show a placeholder image, but it is not the case that the URI does not return any image - it does, but for us it is not a correct one. Hence that functionality would not help us.

Secondly, I know this is pointing towards a failed design in the APIs, that we have to get around doing this to know if the avatar image response is valid according to our guidelines, but the Profiles Service is not specific to our solution but more broad therefore this "hack-y" way was the way to go *for now*.

**Any ideas how to get around validating the headers using Picasso or any other libraries of a URI in order to not download an image for no purpose and not to waste bandwidth?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to skip to the answer, go to point #3 on the list below!**

---

After some time digging around, I have tried couple of approaches and found one that accomplished everything listed above, even though it's not the cleanest way:

> **1. Tried adding OkHttp3 interceptors to Picasso to modify response before passed on**

My first idea was to use Interceptor in OkHttp that we commonly use to modify/add headers to *requests* before sending them out, and not to modify *responses* - which you should NOT do, if possible.

The interceptor looked like the following:

```
private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        okhttp3.Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        if (validate(originalResponse.headers()) {
            return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                   .body(null) //remove the body, stupid
                   .build();
        }
        return originalResponse;
    }
};
```

Then I tried adding this interceptor to a Picasso instance using Jake Wharton's `com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader` library that adds OkHttp3 interceptor support to both Picasso 2.5.2 and Retrofit 2.0.2.

The problem was that the interceptor never got called and I suspected (after researching about it) that it might be caused that the OkHttp version used in Picasso is different that the one I am depending on. Never figured out why it did not get called (even other interceptors), but I quickly realized that the concept behind this approach is broken and I pivoted.

> **2. Tried making a `HEAD` request using Retrofit 2 to verify the headers before making a call using Picasso**

Decided that I have to make 2 separate calls in order to achieve this:
1. A `HEAD` request to validate the response headers separately before the step 2.
2. A `GET` request to download the whole response body containing the image (if step 1. has returned valid)

In my previous approach where I wanted to bundle together these two steps was conceptually wrong, as the body would have been downloaded either way but only dismissed when a criteria was met, therefore wasting bandwidth either way.

I planned on using Retrofit 2 to achieve step 1 and Picasso 2.5 to achieve step 2.

I quickly pivoted from this due to the fact that implementing a Retrofit rest interface for such a simple call would have come with a lot of overhead.

> **3. Settled with doing a `HEAD` call using OkHttp3 to verify the headers, then calling Picasso with the URI**

Similar to approach #2. but instead of using Retrofit to make a `head()` call to the given URI to examine/validate the headers before downloading the image using Picasso into the given ImageView, I decided to use OkHttp3 (which is the foundation for both Picasso and Retrofit by the way).

Shortly, I implemented an AsyncTask that would run a simple OkHttp `head()` call on a given link, which would return me an item that contains the enum type for the avatar and the associated link. This call would happen on a different thread.

The thread that would initialize the other call, once it would receive the feedback from the OkHttp call (using a simple pattern to notify the UI thread), it would process the information and would kick off a Picasso call if needed.

Here is the code below:

```
package com.example;

import android.net.Uri;

public class Avatar {
    AvatarType _avatarType;
    Uri _uri;

    public Avatar(AvatarType type, Uri uri) {
        _avatarType = type;
        _uri = uri;
    }

    public AvatarType getType() {
        return _avatarType;
    }

    public Uri getUri() {
        return _uri;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example;

public enum AvatarType {
    TYPE_X,
    TYPE_Y
}
```

---

```
package com.example;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;

public class AvatarDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Avatar> {

    private OnTaskCompleted _listener;

    public AvatarDownloaderTask(OnTaskCompleted listener){
        _listener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    protected Avatar doInBackground(String... params) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(params[0])
                .head()
                .build();

        try {
            okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            if (Integer.parseInt(response.header("Content-Length")) > 100) {
                return new Avatar(AvatarType.TYPE_Y, Uri.parse(params[0]));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            cancel(true);
        }
        return new Avatar(AvatarType.TYPE_X, Uri.parse(params[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Avatar s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        _listener.onTaskCompleted(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Avatar s) {
        super.onCancelled(s);
        _listener.onTaskCompleted(s);
    }

    public interface OnTaskCompleted{
        void onTaskCompleted(Avatar avatar);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements AvatarDownloaderTask.OnTaskCompleted{

    /* -stripped out code- */

    // Use this call in your activity or fragment that also implements the OnTaskCompleted interface
    private void loadAvatar(String avatarUrl) {
        new AvatarDownloaderTask(this).execute(avatarUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(Avatar avatar) {
        switch (avatar.getType()) {
            case TYPE_X:
                _avatarProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                _avatarImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                _avatarImageViewPlaceholder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case TYPE_Y:
                // Just a helper class with a shared Picasso instance
                ImageHandler.sharedHandler(getContext()).bypassImageResizer(avatar.getUri(), _avatarImageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        _avatarProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        _avatarImageViewPlaceholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        _avatarImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        _avatarProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        _avatarImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        _avatarImageViewPlaceholder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**This is definitely not a clean approach and the API design that forces me to do this is bad to begin with. I am curious to hear feedback from others and suggestions how to improve upon this/fix this in another way. Any other lightweight approach to the AsyncTask? What about passing the data back to the main/UI thread - could that be fixed/improved/eliminated?**

Cheers!